# bootstrap datetimepicker prevent minDate from printing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker and this is my script

```
$('.start_datetime, .end_datetime').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    inline:false,
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    allowInputToggle: true,
    sideBySide:true,
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

In the above script i am initialising `minDate` to today's date but the problem is when i check the result today's date is already coming as printed value of text box but i don't want it to be printed i want it just to restrict it from selecting date previous than today's date.

Comment: Whick picker are you using? For [eonasdan's picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) you can just set [`useCurrent`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent) to `false` to get what you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picker shows today's date because by default the `useCurrent` option is `true`, as stated in the [documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent).

Setting `useCurrent` to `false` will solve your issue, as shown in the following code:

```js
$('.start_datetime, .end_datetime').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    inline: false,
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    allowInputToggle: true,
    sideBySide:true,
    minDate: new Date(),
    useCurrent: false
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date start_datetime">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```